# Not understanding the completion handler in this code

Tags: swift, completionhandler

What is the purpose of 'completion(items)'? I understand that these are used when we don't know when an operation will be finished like download time. However, in this case loadData() is just pulling a plist file from the project directory so i feel like that's a constant time and don't see the need for the completion handler. Also, my textbook says that it returns the annotations array, but I don't see any return statement. I'm new to swift so i apologize if this is not a good question.

```
func fetch(completion: (_ annotations: [RestaurantItem]) -> ()) {
        if items.count > 0 { items.removeAll() }
        for data in loadData() {
            items.append(RestaurantItem(dict: data))
        }
        completion(items)
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is silly, but technically correct (in that it would compile and run), Swift code. It does not feel like the kind of code that a textbook should be introducing you to. And, as you suggest, it does not return an array; it passes an array to the completion handler. The only place you might find this kind of code is in a unit test (and even then, it would be a bit dicey). If this is coming from a textbook, you may be in a course that is not ideal.

Comment: The way that I read this... the function fetch is called with one argument.  The name of that argument is 'completion'. That argument is a closure, that takes as its input an array of RestaurantItem and returns nothing.  The function fills the array items with RestaurantItem's then it calls the line completion(items) calls that closure with the array it just filled.

Comment: @RobNapier If this isn't from a textbook, or if the textbook is not about completion handlers, I would say the code is not necessarily silly. I sometimes write code like this, to allow me to change the function to be an asynchronous one in the future, without breaking the callers. It's a way to be future proof.

Comment: @Sweeper Even if you were to do that (and yes, I have, but certainly not in educational code), IMO you should write it as a `DispatchQueue.async`, because otherwise you're calling the completion handler before the function returns, and that encourages subtle timing bugs or subtle timing dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

We generally use completion handler closures when writing asynchronous code, i.e. in those cases where we’re starting something time consuming (e.g. a network request), but you don’t want to block the caller (typically the main thread) while this relatively slow network request is happening.

So, let’s look at a typical completion handler pattern. Let’s imagine that you’re doing an asynchronous network request with `URLSession`:

```
func fetch(completion: @escaping ([RestaurantItem]) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        // parse the `data`
        let items: [RestaurantItem] = ...
        DispatchQueue.async { completion(items) }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

(I’m using `URLSession` as an example of an asynchronous process. Clearly if you were using Alamofire or Firebase or any asynchronous API, the idea is the same. We call the completion handler closure, `completion`, when the asynchronous request is done.)

This starts the network request, but returns immediately, and it will call `completion` when the network request finishes later. Note, `fetch` should not update the model directly. It just supplies the results to the closure.

Your caller (perhaps a view controller) takes on the responsibility of updating the model and the UI when then `completion` closure is later called:

```
var items: [RestaurantItems] = []   // start with empty array

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetch { items in
        print("got items", items)
        self.items = items          // this is where we update our model
        self.tableView.reloadData() // this is where we update our UI, a table view in this example
    }
    print("finishing viewDidLoad")
}
```

If we watch our console, we’ll see the “finishing viewDidLoad” message *before* the “got items” message. But the closure we supplied to `fetch` does the updating of the model and triggering a reloading of the UI.

This is an over simplified example, but that’s the basic idea of completion handler closures, to allow us to provide a block of code that can be performed when some asynchronous task is done, while allowing `fetch` to immediately return so that we don’t block the UI.

But, the only reason we go through this complicated closure pattern because the task performed by `fetch` runs asynchronously. If `fetch` wasn’t doing something asynchronous (and it doesn’t appear to do so in your example), we simply would not use this closure pattern at all. You’d just `return` the results.

---

So, let’s go back to your example.

There are a few issues:

1. It doesn’t make sense to update `items` and also return the results (whether returning directly or using a closure). You would do one or the other, but not both. So, I might suggest that you make a local variable, and pass the results in the closure (much like my asynchronous pattern above). For example:

   ```
   func fetch(completion: (_ annotations: [RestaurantItem]) -> ()) {
       var items: [RestaurantItem] = []
       for data in loadData() {
           items.append(RestaurantItem(dict: data))
       }
       completion(items)
   }
   ```
2. I might further simplify this using `map`, e.g.:

   ```
   func fetch(completion: (_ annotations: [RestaurantItem]) -> ()) {
       let items = loadData().map { RestaurantItem(dict: $0)) }
       completion(items)
   }
   ```
3. Regardless of which of the above you do, you could do:

   ```
   func viewDidLoad() {
       ...
       fetch { items in
           self.items = items
       }
   }
   ```
4. But that’s very misleading. If you see a method with a name of `fetch` with a closure, future readers are just going to assume it’s an asynchronous method (as that’s the only reason we’d adopt that pattern). If it’s synchronous, I’d simplify it to just `return` the results:

   ```
   func fetch() -> [RestaurantItem] {
       return loadData().map { RestaurantItem(dict: $0)) }
   }
   ```

   And

   ```
   func viewDidLoad() {
       ...
       items = fetch()
   }
   ```

Needless to say, if `fetch` was asynchronous, then you *would* use the `@escaping` closure, as shown in the beginning of my answer. That is the typical closure example.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, functions with completion handlers don't need return statements -- instead, just call the completion handler (`completion(items)`)

So you know how function parameters can accept `String`s, `Int`s, etc?

```
func doSomething(inputThing: Int) {
                             ^ this is the type (an Int)
}
```

They can also accept closures. In your example the `completion` parameter accepts a closure.

```
func fetch(completion: (_ annotations: [RestaurantItem]) -> ()) {
                       ^ this is the type (a closure)
}
```

Closures are basically blocks of code that you can pass around. Usually, if a function accepts a closure as a parameter, you refer to the closure as the "completion handler" (because it will usually be called at the end of the function).

Your closure also specifies an input of type `[RestaurantItem]` and an output of `()` / `Void` (Void because the closure itself won't return anything). The `_ annotations:` part is unnecessary: just do this:

```
func fetch(completion: ([RestaurantItem]) -> ()) {
}
```

When you call the function, you'll need to pass in a closure, and assign the input to a variable.

```
fetch(completion: { restaurantItems in
    /// do something with restaurantItems (assigned to the input)
})
```

You'll call this closure at the end of `func fetch(completion: (_ annotations: [RestaurantItem]) -> ())`.

```
func fetch(completion: (_ annotations: [RestaurantItem]) -> ()) {
    if items.count > 0 { items.removeAll() }
    for data in loadData() {
        items.append(RestaurantItem(dict: data))
    }
    completion(items) /// call the closure!
    /// this is a completion handler because you called it at the end of the function
}
```

Calling `completion(items)` passes `items` into the input of the closure, which is assigned to `restaurantItems`.

Usually closures are used for functions that will take time to run, like downloading files. But in your example, `loadData()` looks like it will happen instantly, so you should just go with a normal function with a return type.

```
func fetch() -> [RestaurantItem] {
    if items.count > 0 { items.removeAll() }
    for data in loadData() {
        items.append(RestaurantItem(dict: data))
    }
    return items
}

let restaurantItems = fetch()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! Question - where is the implementation for completion? You say it's assigned to restaurantItems but i don't see where it assigns it to RestaurantItems.

Comment: You're not explicitly saying something like `restaurantItems = items`. So the function, `fetch`, accepts a closure as a parameter, and the closure's type is `([RestaurantItem]) -> ()`. The closure that you pass in is `{ restaurantItems in ... }` -- so `restaurantItems` will be the input. Then, when you call the closure inside `fetch`, you plug `items` into the input, which is `restaurantItems`. Think of closures like functions -- `restaurantItems` is the parameter, and you pass `items` in.

Comment: okay so items gets passed into the closure but it doesn't return anything so what is the closure exactly doing when items gets passed into it?

Comment: Well that is up to you! Do whatever you want with `restaurantItems`, for example, update a tableview like what @Rob said below. In my answer, replace `/// do something with restaurantItems (assigned to the input)` with whatever you want to do.

Comment: but in the case of completion(items), what is that exactly doing? After items is passed to the closure...what is happening based off the code i've given? Sorry if my understanding of closures is off.

Comment: When you write `completion(items)`, you're **calling** the closure and passing `items` into the input (think of it as a parameter) of the closure. This is the equivalent of **calling** a function and passing `items` into one of its parameters. But you can't call a function if there isn't a function to begin with, right? Same goes for closures. That's why you *pass a closure* into the `fetch` function. Inside this closure you assign `restaurantItems` (think of it as the name of the parameter) to the input. You call that closure when you do `completion(items)`